# MYSQL multiple select queries in one repeating results

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have a query with some subqueries. The subqueries work fine on there own but when put together in one big query the returned results are just repeated.

The query:

```
SELECT
kpi.kra_id AS kra,
kpi.id AS kpi, 
(
    SELECT 
    ROUND(AVG(sp.progress), 2) 
    FROM `submissions` AS sub
    LEFT JOIN `sub_performancemeasures` sp ON sp.sub_id = sub.id
    WHERE sub.programme = 'programme' 
    AND sub.submission_year = '2015/2016' 
    AND sub.state = '2'
    AND sub.period = '1'
    AND pm.kpi_id = kpi.id
) AS p1_programme_score,
(
    SELECT 
    ROUND(AVG(sp.progress), 2) 
    FROM `submissions` AS sub
    LEFT JOIN `sub_performancemeasures` sp ON sp.sub_id = sub.id
    WHERE sub.programme = 'programme' 
    AND sub.submission_year = '2015/2016' 
    AND sub.state = '2'
    AND sub.period = '2'
    AND pm.kpi_id = kpi.id
) AS p2_programme_score
FROM `kpis` kpi
LEFT JOIN `performance_measures` pm ON kpi.id = pm.kpi_id
GROUP BY kpi.id
```

the results look like this:

[image: MySQL Results]

What I'm looking for is a each KPI to show its own score for each p1 and p2 column.

Comment: Can you post a schema from your database?

Comment: It's because your sub queries have no tie to your outer ones. `pm.kpi_id = kpi.id` is on the outer tables and no ties to the sub queries.  How does `SP` or `SUB` relate to `KPI` or `PM`?

Comment: Thank you @xQbert that's helped me get the answer! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so huge thanks to [Jerodev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/743016/jerodev) and [xQBert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1016435/xqbert) for pointing me in the right direction. The new working query is below:

```
SELECT
kpi.kra_id AS kra,
kpi.id AS kpi, 
(
    SELECT 
    ROUND(AVG(sp.progress), 2) 
    FROM `submissions` AS sub
    LEFT JOIN `sub_performancemeasures` sp ON sp.sub_id = sub.id
    LEFT JOIN `performance_measures` pm ON pm.id = sp.pm_id
    WHERE sub.programme = 'programme' 
    AND sub.submission_year = '2015/2016' 
    AND sub.state = '2'
    AND sub.period = '1'
    AND pm.kpi_id = kpi.id
) AS p1_programme_score,
(
    SELECT 
    ROUND(AVG(sp.progress), 2) 
    FROM `submissions` AS sub
    LEFT JOIN `sub_performancemeasures` sp ON sp.sub_id = sub.id
    LEFT JOIN `performance_measures` pm ON pm.id = sp.pm_id
    WHERE sub.programme = 'programme' 
    AND sub.submission_year = '2015/2016' 
    AND sub.state = '2'
    AND sub.period = '2'
    AND pm.kpi_id = kpi.id
) AS p2_programme_score
FROM `kpis` kpi
GROUP BY kpi.id
```

The difference in this query is where the joining of the performance_measures table is. It was on the main query but it needed to be tied to the subqueries so I moved it and VIOLA!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to fix the problem, because you don't include the data structure.  But, I can identify the probable cause.

Each subquery has this condition:

```
AND pm.kpi_id = kpi.id
```

Neither `pm` nor `kpi` are in the subqueries, so this just repeats the `join` condition in the outer query.  Presumably, you want the `kpi_id` to match some table in the subquery, either `sub` or `sp`.